# How to get index number in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView with a lot of items, and I need to get index of every item in ListView.

```
        Item 1
        Item 2
        Item 3
        Item 4
        Item 5
```

for example "Item 1" = 0 ,
"Item 2" = 1

Comment: So what's the problem? And why do you want the index or every item?

Comment: int a = Convert.ToInt32(PersonListView.SelectedIndex);
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
I did it like this, and I need to create an event if a = 1 and a = 2.

Comment: You need to create an event on what? selection of an item? SelectedIndex will give the index of only the selected item not all the items.

Comment: for example 
if(a = 2) MessageBox.Show(a.ToString()); 
this message have to load only for Item 2 and Item 3

Comment: Use the for loop as mentioned by Excalibrus and then add if condition inside it.

Comment: foreach(var item in listView.Items) {
   index = listView.Items.IndexOf(item );
if(index =2)
MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
} 
Like this? Its not working

Comment: Yes, but since this is C# you will have to use double = (i.e. `==`) for comparison. Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) for more details on operators in C#

Comment: Sure I know, I use == but I did only for 
     if (Convert.ToInt32(index) == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());}
and for the record "Item 0" (0) it works too.(Display 1)

Answer (score 5):

```
listView.Items.IndexOf(Item1);
```

if you need index of each you can get in foreach loop, like:

```
foreach(var item in listView.Items) {
   index = listView.Items.IndexOf(item );
}
```

Comment: int a = Convert.ToInt32(PersonListView.SelectedIndex);
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
I did it like this, and I need to create an event if a = 1 and a = 2.